# ¿Como mantener la sesión iniciada en una app Flutter, con Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-auth

Muy buenas noches tengan todos colegas.
EL problema es el siguiente: Tengo una app, en la que estoy usando servicios de Firebase, entre ellos AUTH; y en base a este, me gustaría que la sesión se mantenga.
Leí la [documentación oficial](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state) que esta el método justamente para estar a la escucha de los cambios en el mismo inicio de sesión.

¿Como lo estoy haciendo?, simple. En el archivo main de mi app,declaro una variable booleana,después ejecuto el propio método que se propone en la documentación oficial,si el usuario es NULL sabemos que no hay nadie con sesión activa, por lo que mi variable la dejo en false; por el contrario si hay una sesión activa, a la variable le doy el valor de true.

Ahora, en base a esta variable, y en el parámetro "home" del Material App, en base a un ternario evaluando a mi variable, que muestre la pantalla del login o la principal. Sabiendo que login si no hay usuario con sesión habilitada y la principal si ya hay un usuario. (Nota: use ambos métodos sugeridos por la documentación).

Mi código:

```
bool state = false;
    FirebaseAuth.instance
      .authStateChanges()
      .listen((User? user) {
        if (user == null) {
          print('User is currently signed out!');
          state = false;
        } else {
          print('User is signed in!');
          state = true;
        }
      });
    
      FirebaseAuth.instance
      .idTokenChanges()
      .listen((User? user) {
        if (user == null) {
          print('User is currently signed out!');
          state = false;
        } else {
          print('User is signed in!');
          state = true;
        }
      });
```

Y al momento de evaluar que pantalla voy a renderizar, hago lo siguiente:

```
home: (state == true) ? MainstageScreen() : LoginScreen(),
```

El problema radica en que, siempre me renderiza la pantalla del login "loginScreen()". Como si nunca en los metodos para ver si esta o no loggueado entrara y se quedara siempre con el false con el que fue declarada la variable.

Pero cuando veo la terminal del VS Code, si me imprime "User is currently signed out!" y "User is signed in!" respectivamente del caso. Pero jamas cambia de valor la variable y siempre se va al login.

¿En que me estoy equivocando?, ¿Que puedo hacer?, ¿Necesito ejecutar el metodo en un Future y llamarlo en un stream builder?
Agradezco sus respuestas. Gracias.

Comment: Buenas, escuchar el método Auth state change es correcto. Lo que no debe estar funcionandote es la variable state (tal vez te falta un setstate para que dispare el build?) deberías poner ese método en un screen splash para decidir a qué pantalla ir y no mostrar una y al segundo renderizar otra

Comment: Okey, deja lo intento.

Comment: Funciono, añado la respuesta para los demás usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

OK, muy bien. Funciono eso:
Comparto la solución para que los demás usuarios que se les presente el problema la tengan:
Se crea justamente el splash screen, y con el método initState(), dispararemos un método que contenga el método que propone la documentación oficial, y en base a sus condiciones que tiene dentro, le decimos que navegue a la pantalla que queramos que se renderize. Solamente en le home mandamos llamar a la SplashScreen.

Del modo que (En el SplashScreen):

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _navigateToHome();
  }

  _navigateToHome() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2500), () {});
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
        //print('User is currently signed out!');
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()));
      } else {
        //print('User is signed in!');
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => PantallaPrincipal()));
      }
    });
  }
```

Y en el Main en el apartado del Home:

```
home: SplashScreen(),
```

Agradecemos a: Franco Berardi por la respuesta.

Comment: Genial! De esta forma te anda el logout? Te sigue disparando el evento para redirigirte al login de nuevo? Sino te funciona te subo cómo lo resolví yo. Tiene algunas diferencias

Comment: Si me funciono mi buen franco, todo perfecto. Pero si igual gustas poner tu respuesta para que los demás usuarios puedan verla y tener dos fuentes.